# Why is the superlaser dish in the southern hemisphere of the Death Star rather than the northern one?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

There are some images in which the superlaser dish of the Death Star appears in the southern hemisphere, not the northern hemisphere as it usually does. Why is this?

---

Note: the idea for this question came from [this site](https://www.moviemistakes.com/film1226/answers/page3).

Comment: This might help how you think about positioning in space: http://cleverthingstosay.com/2010/01/28/space-and-the-y-axis/

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the real reason has something to do with how foreigners often depict the Earth. When shown to Americans, the globe is most recognizable if North America is centered. If shown to an Asian, Asia is centered. And so on. It wouldn't surprise me if the marketing team knew that foreigners would perceive the Death Star differently one way or the other.

Comment: Coz "straya"? Seriously though, how do you know *you're* not upside down?

Comment: In space, no one can hear the geography teacher scream.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### In space, orientation is relative

Unless the Death Star is very close to a planet or other massive body, any significant gravity it produces is artificial. As such, whether the laser dish is in the southern or northern hemispheres is purely a matter of camera angle.

Sometimes it looks like this:

[image: Image of the Death Star in space, illuminated from the right; the Death Star is viewed from directly above the equator with the superlaser dish in the upper right quadrant.]

Other times it looks more like this:

[image: An X-wing chases a TIE fighter through space, with 2 red bolts streaking forward from the X-wing and past the TIE fighter. The fighters are both flying from the upper right to the lower left and in the upper-left corner of the frame a quadrant of the Death Star appears. Slightly more than half the height of the Death Star is visible, but only half its width; the superlaser dish is centred in the visible part of the lower hemisphere.]

**But in either case, the laser disk is in the *same position* relative to the ship itself.**

Many shots are taken from the point of view of the ships flying around the Death Star, so that probably influences what the apparent orientation is, as is probably the case in the second picture.

So another answer might be:

### In order to give the impression of flying around the Death Star

Comment: +1 Or in the Western Hemisphere. Or Eastern Hemisphere.

Comment: Or as Wiggins would say. "The enemy's gate is down".

Comment: Idea for next Alien sequel:  "In space, no one can see you stand upside down"

Comment: North and south don't have anything to do with *gravity*, they're relative to the rotational axis of a planet. I don't assume the Death Star has a fixed rotation since that would be pretty inconvenient for a weapon. It does clearly have a division in hemispheres so I suppose you could name one of them north and the other one south if you liked.

Comment: @Joren Relative to the rotational axis (in that this is how they're different from the East and West hemispheres), but also arbitrary (in that which one is North and which South could be swapped).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Indeed. For planets in the solar system the convention is to have north point in that direction that makes it lie in the same hemisphere with respect to the ecliptic as the Earth's north pole does, but obviously that's not very useful for bodies outside the solar system. You could perhaps instead use 'north' for the direction for which, if you put an observer towards the north looking down upon the body, he'd see the body rotating counter-clockwise, like Earth does. But of course at this point you're just making things up.

Comment: @Luaan: Why? They still rotate around a definite axis, albeit slowly. I don't see what's special about Neptune, its rotation is pretty similar to Earth.

Comment: @Joren I'm not sure what I meant with Neptune anymore, probably a brain burp. But Venus and Uranus are interesting - Uranus "rolls" over on its orbit, so its "North pole" is on (almost) the same plane as its orbital plane; we use your second approach there, the first one doesn't make any sense, since the axis isn't anywhere near to perpendicular to the ecliptic. Venus is more fun - it rotates clockwise in your first approach (North pole "aligned" with Earth's North pole), while your second approach makes it "flipped" (North pole "aligned" with Earth's South pole).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: For a rotating body, north and south are not arbitrary; they are assigned by the right-hand-rule (when the fingers of your right hand curve in the direction of rotation, your thumb points north.)

Comment: @kundor Indeed; that's what arbitrary means. :) But to avoid the negative connotations that tend to swamp the actual definition of “arbitrary”, I probably should have said “conventional”; the point is that it's nothing inherent in the body involved, and entirely assigned by the discretion of the observer. (Consider that in a galaxy far away and a long time ago, they could easily use a left-hand rule for the same.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I disagree. The meaning of "north" is defined for rotating bodies by the right-hand rule. I use it just like I can describe Chewbacca as "fuzzy" without worrying that this term has a different definition in Basic. Although the agreed-upon definitions we use are of course in some sense "arbitrary," saying so here is like answering "Is Tatooine dry?" by claiming the meaning of "dry" is arbitrary and you might as well call it "wet".

Comment: @kundor There's a difference between intrinsic properties that are perceived relatively (fuzziness, dryness), and conventional properties that are assigned wholly arbitrarily (North and South on planets, let alone a non-rotating space station), but as this is neither Phil.se or ELU, I'll leave any further consideration of why that's necessarily true as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 62):

It's always in the northern hemisphere. *You're* upside down.

> [The Emperor's throne room](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_throne_room) on the second Death Star was on the top of a 100-story tower located on the **north pole** of the superweapon.

---

> **The Emperor's throne room** on the first Death Star was located in an observation dome at the top of a tower placed directly next to the station's superlaser. The platform **served as Palpatine's watchtower in order to view the laser's firing demonstrations.**

Subjectively, being poised to *fire down* on something is much more 'menacing' then just firing *at* it.

Comment: So *that's* what happened to his skin. *"Hey, Tony... right? Can we put my tower back a little bit this time?"*